# Query upon Ruby Active record object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My code is this

```
users = UserLocation.find(:all, :conditions => "hide_my_location = 0 and datediff(now(), updated_at) < 2 and id != 196")
near_users = users.find(:all, :conditions => "substr(geohash, 1, 11) = 'abcdef'")
count = near_users.count
```

it return s error in ruby 1.8.7

**wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
Rails 2.3.6
**activerecord (2.3.6)**

Comment: Which version of ActiveRecord?

Comment: Those two version together are impossible.

Comment: Should `abcdef` be between single quotes? Or do you have a column named `abcdef`??

Comment: abcdef is a string in single quoted